# Making a request for api running into AWS instance with docker

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi guys i have one api running into aws ec2 instance, and it's running with docker
[img docker running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQSc3.png)

And i had configurated the instance open for http and https:
[Image of configuration ec2 instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQZJM.png)

I tried to make a post to this DNS IPv4 Public, although i received a Request timed out error.
I'm a begginer in AWS hehe

I tried to make a post to the api with the ip but I don't received a 200 status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you first check your whole configuration.  Making an EC2 instances (and the apps running on it) accessible to the internet is not so simple.

So you need to set-up and check the settings for;

- VPC
- Subnet
- EC2 Security Groups
- Access Control lists
- Internet Gateway
- Routes
- Elastic IP/load balancer (if you are using one)

Go through these one at a time and check that they all have the right access rights, ports, permissions etc.